# How do I find the index of the group of numbers a number belongs to in a square table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, coordinates

Here is an **8x8** table of **64** cells, each containing a number

```
| 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7|
| 8| 9|10|11|12|13|14|15|
|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|
|24|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|
|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|
|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|
|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|
|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|
```

If we mentally split the table into tiles of 4 cells each we will end up with:

```
index:0    index:1      index:12  index:15
| 0| 1|    | 2| 3|      |48|49|   |54|55|
| 8| 9| ,  |10|11| .... |56|57| , |62|63|
```

I want to create a method that based on the number passed to it it will return **the index of the tile** this number belongs to.

```
getTileIndexFor(8, ...)  // returns 0
getTileIndexFor(11, ...) // returns 1
getTileIndexFor(62, ...) // returns 15
getTileIndexFor(55, ...) // returns 15
etc..
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
function getTileIndexFor(number, ...) { 
  // ????
}
 
let tiles = [/* an array of tiles, each tile itself being an array of { numberWithCoords } */]
let numbersPerTileSide  = 2 // i.e. a 4x4 tile (should also work with any multiple of 2)
let numbersPerTableSide = 8 // should also work with any multiple of {numbersPerTileSide}

// making a 8x8 table of numbers from 0 to 63
let tableOfNumbers = [...Array(numbersPerTableSide * numbersPerTableSide).keys()]
    
tableOfNumbers.forEach((index) => {
    let x = index % numbersPerTableSide
    let y = Math.floor(index / numbersPerTableSide)

    // get current number alongs with its x & y in the table
    let numberWithCoords = { number: index, x, y  }

    let tileIndex = getTileIndexFor(number, ...)

    // if tile doesn't exist create it
    tiles[tileIndex] = tiles[tileIndex] || []

    // push current number into the correct tile
    tiles[tileIndex].push(numberWithCoords) 
})

console.log(tiles)
```

should log:

```
[
  [
    { number: 0, x: 0, y: 0 },
    { number: 1, x: 1, y: 0 },
    { number: 8, x: 0, y: 1 },
    { number: 9, x: 1, y: 1 }
  ],
  ....,
  [
    { number: 54, x: 6, y: 6 },
    { number: 55, x: 7, y: 6 },
    { number: 62, x: 6, y: 7 },
    { number: 63, x: 7, y: 7 }
  ]
]
```

Comment: y = Math.floor(index / 8), x = index % 8

Comment: Wait, why are you calling `getTileIndexFor(n)`, but define it as `getTileIndexFor(x, y, numbersPerTileSide, numbersPerTableSide)`?

Comment: I've updated the OP. I don't know what params `getTileIndexFor()` should get actually.

Comment: @SproutCoder Maybe this function should accept all necessary arguments? I'd suggest having a tile size (like you already have) and then the number of tiles in x and y axis (instead of total number of numbers, because it needs to be dividable anyway) and then the number we're looking for.

Comment: Yes it should take all necessary arguments, no hardcoded  values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the index of 2x2 parts.

```js
function getIndex(i) {
    let col = Math.floor(i / cellCols) % (cols / cellCols),
        row = Math.floor(i / (rows * cellRows));

    return col + row * (rows / cellRows);
}

const
    result = []
    cols = 8,
    rows = 8,
    cellCols = 2,
    cellRows = 2;

for (let y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
        const number = y * cols + x;
        (result[getIndex(number)] ??= []).push({ number, x, y });
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Could you please integrate this with my code so that I can accept it as a complete answer ? Thanks :)

Comment: Or maybe at least replace all hardcoded values (like 2,4,8,16) with variables so that I understand what they represent ? Thanks :)